# JavaScript image zooming - circular border

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to implement JavaScript based image zoom feature similar to the ones mentioned here:
http://www.intenseblog.com/design/8-amazing-javascript-image-zoom-scripts.html

However, unlike the ones mentioned in the link, I'm trying to achieve a circular border for the zoom control instead of rectangle or square.

Is it achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could possibly use the border radius property to shape the div (or whatever) by setting the radius to half the width.

Comment: That may not work in some versions of IE as it does not support corner radius.

Comment: Thanks smitec. I tested in Firefox and it works. For Safari, I found the equivalent property to be -webkit-border-radius. The div is getting rounded, but the zoomed portion still appears as a rectangle. So, in this particular case, I'm only partially able to achieve the expected behavior. Not tested in IE yet but came across this in case it helps anyone: refer this: code.google.com/p/curved-corner